# Get sign-in status from Office 365 via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office365, exchangewebservices

I've found the below snip of code from [here](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2016/06/list-office-365-group-members-using-powershell.html) and it works really well.

```
$Groups = Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize 5
$Groups | ForEach-Object {
$group = $_
Get-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $group.Name -LinkType Members -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object {
      New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
       Group = $group.DisplayName
       Member = $_.Name
       EmailAddress = $_.PrimarySMTPAddress
       RecipientType= $_.RecipientType
}}}
```

However, I want to be able to either filter by or list the sign-in status from O365 as well.

[image]

I've tried adding a new variable but I can't figure out what the identifier for that field is.  The code below shows my attempt with SignInStatus, I've also tried a few other phrases I thought it might be but none have worked.

```
$Groups = Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize 5
$Groups | ForEach-Object {
$group = $_
Get-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $group.Name -LinkType Members -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object {
      New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
       Group = $group.DisplayName
       Member = $_.Name
       EmailAddress = $_.PrimarySMTPAddress
       RecipientType= $_.RecipientType
       Status = $_.SignInStatus
}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The property is `BlockCredential`, but it can't be found from Exchange. You must fetch it from Office 365. This should do the trick, if user's primary email address matches O365 user name:

```
Status = (GetMsolUser -UserPrincipalName $($_.PrimarySMTPAddress)).BlockCredential
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18778730)

Comment: Made adjustments to the answer and added actual code.